# Is there a way to log off all of the users in a single command?

Tags: windows, rdp

Hope everyone doing great.

I wanted to Logoff multiple users from single syntax through command line.

Now, if I have the 10 users on that machine and I wa t to exclude 2 users and Logoff 8 users.

If their is a way to do from command line share your input.

Thanks...

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to Stackoverflow. i believe you should try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) instead of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QUser /server:ComputerName` to list users and then log them off with `Logoff sessionID /server:ComputerName`.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/269574/how-can-i-automatically-log-out-users-from-a-windows-machine) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response one thing can I pass multiple session ID’s in single syntax like Logoff 2 3 4 /server:computername

Comment: You'll have to write a script for that as far as I know.